# SqlDataReader throws Exception when trying to Load data into DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

I am trying to load a list of Menu Items into a DataGrid in WPF, and can sucessfully only return one row from the table. I have tried to create a for loop that would read into each row and load it into `dtsizes`, but I get an exception stating my procedure or function has too many arguments specified.

```
private DataTable GetSizesData()
    {
        //NOTE: compiler will through nullpointer error if datatable is null, so create an object

        DataTable dtsizes = new DataTable();

        //get and store the datatable through sql connection -> applicationsetting.cs
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApplicationSetting.ConnectionString()))
        { 
        //runs sql command usp load pizzas (see .txt file)
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Pizzas_LoadAllPizzas", con))
        {
        
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    //load procedure and given params
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@main_identifier", i);

                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    con.Close();
                    dtsizes.Load(sdr);
                }
            //read data then load into dtsizes datatable
        }
    }
        return dtsizes;
    }
```

Here is my usp_PizzasAllPizzas SQL Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Pizzas_LoadAllPizzas]
(

    @main_identifier INT
)
AS
    BEGIN
        --DECLARE @IsSelected BIT
        --SET @IsSelected = 0

        SELECT [main_identifier] AS 'ID'
               ,[main_name] AS 'Title'
          
           --,@IsSelected AS 'Select'
    FROM [dbo].[main_cata] WHERE 
        [main_identifier] = @main_identifier
        

END
```

I am sure the answer here is simple but I cannot figure out how to load all entries from the table into my dataGrid. I have tried defining a separate INT and looping through that in a separate part of the class but still have not got it working. Any feedback or comments helps and thank you so much!
[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yXMM.png)

Comment: In your second iteration you are trying to add a parameter that was already added in your first iteration

Comment: Move all the `cmd` operations outside of the loop besides the execute.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing connection in for loop.
why you did not write query just like this

```
SELECT [main_identifier] AS 'ID'
    ,[main_name] AS 'Title'        
FROM [dbo].[main_cata] WHERE 
    [main_identifier] < @main_identifier
```

and in C# code just remove for loop.